# ASP.NET Core Web API Conventional routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

In ASP.NET Core Web API I am using Attribute routing and I need to move it to conventional routing.

```
 [ApiController]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    [Route("GetHome")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Getdeatils([FromBody] myclass cs, string system)
    {
    }
 }
```

With Attribute routing the URL `localhost/GetHome?system=abc` works and triggers `Getdeatils` method.

I am trying to move same URL pattern to startup, but I am unable to achieve it.I have removed `[ApiController]` from controller class I have tried below code in startup. But it is not working.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "mycustom",
               pattern: "GetHome",
               defaults: "{controller=Home}/{action=Getdeatils}/{system?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{system?}");
            
        });
```

URL:`localhost/Home/Getdeatils?system=abc`  - This works fine

URL:`localhost/GetHome?system=abc`  - This is not working.

How this can be achieved without changing the URL format.

Comment: Your defaults parameter looks wrong, see docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conventional-route-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this code:

```
app.UseEndPoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "mycustom",
           pattern: "GetHome",
           defaults: new {controller="Home", action="GetDetails"});
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{system?}");
}
```

Please let me know if it works as expected.